# SQL Statement: Group BY not working as it is needed to

Tags: sql, group-by

I am trying to get a count of the number of students that are absent at a particular day. I am going to be providing a sample of the view here:

[image]

I am trying to get a count a view that shows me School_Name, Absent_Date, Name and Student_ID from the data above where a student has skipped more than or equal to 4 periods.

My SQL statement is like the following:

```
SELECT [PERIOD], [Student_ID], [ABS_DATE]  
FROM t_database
GROUP BY [Bell_Period]  
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
```

However, it does not show it, I have not worked with a scenario such as this thus, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your issue lies partly in your `GROUP BY`.  You want to group by student_id (You'll have to group by some other things too)

Comment: Ditto to Del's comment, first thing I noticed was that your group by is "bell_period" not "period" like you have named the row in your sample data.

Comment: How about: SELECT Student_id, count(distinct period) as "periods_attended", date) from t_database where periods_attended < 4 group by date, student_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by the columns you want in the result, and aggregate (here - count) across those you don't:

```
SELECT   school_name, absent_date, name, student_id
FROM     t_database
GROUP BY school_name, absent_date, name, student_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) >= 4
```